# AWS S3 SDK Javascript - MalformedXML response when trying to restore a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been uploading and restoring files from S3 Glacier & Deep Archive, and I wanted to add  a feature that would make a copy the restored file with another prefix ("_restoreComplete"). According to the docs, this would be pretty simple: by adding OutputLocation to the params object sent with restoreObject().

My params looks like this:

```
let restoreParams = {
    Bucket: "bucketExample",
    Key: "file.txt",
    RestoreRequest: {
        Days: 1,
        GlacierJobParameters: {
            Tier: "Standard"
        },
        
        OutputLocation: {
            S3: {
                BucketName: "bucketExample",
                Prefix: "_restoreComplete"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

However, calling restoreObject with these params throws a MalformedXML exception:

> MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

I have looked around and found no viable solution. I saw a mention to add ExposedHeaders to the bucket's CORS config, but that didn't do a dent.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

PS: Please note that restoring files with the same params object (without OutputLocation) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Boto3 documentation, `Days` should not be used with restores that specify `OutputLocation`.

Moreover, one thing I need to point out is that in your example, the restored object would have "filename" `_restoreComplete` but you probably want something like `file.txt.restoreComplete`.

What I'd do is use the lifecycle policy feature of S3 and set it to expire (a.k.a. *delete*) objects after 1 day. I could also add prefix filtering rules so that only objects whose keys end with `restoreComplete` expire.